# Jquery accordion not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I'm trying to make an accordion for a FAQ section on a page using Jquery but I can't seem to get it right.

What I want to do is when the plus icon is clicked all opened reply boxes have to slide up and the one I clicked has to slide up.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var open;
 $(".faq_reply_container").slideUp();
    $(".faq_show_icon").click(function(){
   $(".faq_reply_container").slideUp();
        open = $(this).nextAll("first:faq_reply_container");
  open.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.faq_container{width:100%; height:auto; display:flex; flex-direction:column;}

.faq_question_reply_container{width:100%; height:auto; outline:2px solid #00BDE7; margin:5px 0px 5px 0px; }

.faq_question_container{outline:2px solid #00BDE7; background-color:white; width:100%; height:45px; display:flex; align-items:center; padding-left:15px; justify-content:space-between;}

.faq_question{font-family:Rubik; font-weight:600; color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0); font-size:18px;}

.faq_show_icon{width:39px; height:39px; outline:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); margin-right:3px; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; font-weight:900; color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0); font-size:50px;}

.faq_show_icon:hover{cursor:pointer; background-color:#F5F5F5;}

.faq_reply_container{width:100%; height:auto; padding:15px 45px 15px 15px; background-color:#F5F5F5;}

.faq_reply{font-family:Patua One; color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); font-size:15px; line-height:23px;}

.article_container{width:77%; height:100%;  padding:15px 15px 15px 15px; overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article_container" style="">
     <div class="faq_container" style="">
   <div class="faq_question_reply_container" style="">
       <div class="faq_question_container" style="">
        <span class="faq_question" style="">¿Esto es una prefunta seria asi que espero una respuesta seria?</span>
        <div class="faq_show_icon" style="">+</div>
    </div>
    <div class="faq_reply_container" style="">
        <p class="faq_reply" style="">Waynabox es una nueva forma de viajar por Europa. Te escaparás durante tres días a una ciudad sorpresa desde 150€, con vuelos de ida y vuelta y alojamiento incluidos.Descarta las ciudades que no quieres visitar (una gratuïta y, las siguientes, por 5€ cada una) y haz tu reserva. Dos días antes de salir, te mandaremos los billetes y descubrirás cuál es tu ciudad. ¡Atrévete a vivir tu próxima aventura este fin de semana!</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="faq_question_reply_container" style="">
       <div class="faq_question_container" style="">
        <span class="faq_question" style="">¿Esto es una prefunta seria asi que espero una respuesta seria?</span>
        <div class="faq_show_icon" style="">+</div>
    </div>
    <div class="faq_reply_container" style="">
        <p class="faq_reply" style="">Waynabox es una nueva forma de viajar por Europa. Te escaparás durante tres días a una ciudad sorpresa desde 150€, con vuelos de ida y vuelta y alojamiento incluidos.Descarta las ciudades que no quieres visitar (una gratuïta y, las siguientes, por 5€ cada una) y haz tu reserva. Dos días antes de salir, te mandaremos los billetes y descubrirás cuál es tu ciudad. ¡Atrévete a vivir tu próxima aventura este fin de semana!</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="faq_question_reply_container" style="">
       <div class="faq_question_container" style="">
        <span class="faq_question" style="">¿Esto es una prefunta seria asi que espero una respuesta seria?</span>
        <div class="faq_show_icon" style="">+</div>
    </div>
    <div class="faq_reply_container" style="">
        <p class="faq_reply" style="">Waynabox es una nueva forma de viajar por Europa. Te escaparás durante tres días a una ciudad sorpresa desde 150€, con vuelos de ida y vuelta y alojamiento incluidos.Descarta las ciudades que no quieres visitar (una gratuïta y, las siguientes, por 5€ cada una) y haz tu reserva. Dos días antes de salir, te mandaremos los billetes y descubrirás cuál es tu ciudad. ¡Atrévete a vivir tu próxima aventura este fin de semana!</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$($this)` to `$(this)`:

```
open = $(this).nextAll("first:faq_reply_container");
```

You mentioned:

> "What I want to do is when the plus icon is clicked all opened reply boxes have to slide up and the one I clicked has to slide up"

Write the following line inside event listener:

```
$(this).closest('.faq_question_reply_container')
       .find('.faq_reply_container')
       .slideDown();
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".faq_reply_container").slideUp();
    
    $(".faq_show_icon").click(function(){
      $(".faq_reply_container").slideUp();
  
      $(this).closest('.faq_question_reply_container')
             .find('.faq_reply_container')
             .slideDown();
    });
});
```

```css
.faq_container{width:100%; height:auto; display:flex; flex-direction:column;}

.faq_question_reply_container{width:100%; height:auto; outline:2px solid #00BDE7; margin:5px 0px 5px 0px; }

.faq_question_container{outline:2px solid #00BDE7; background-color:white; width:100%; height:45px; display:flex; align-items:center; padding-left:15px; justify-content:space-between;}

.faq_question{font-family:Rubik; font-weight:600; color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0); font-size:18px;}

.faq_show_icon{width:39px; height:39px; outline:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); margin-right:3px; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; font-weight:900; color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0); font-size:50px;}

.faq_show_icon:hover{cursor:pointer; background-color:#F5F5F5;}

.faq_reply_container{width:100%; height:auto; padding:15px 45px 15px 15px; background-color:#F5F5F5;}

.faq_reply{font-family:Patua One; color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); font-size:15px; line-height:23px;}

.article_container{width:77%; height:100%;  padding:15px 15px 15px 15px; overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article_container" style="">
     <div class="faq_container" style="">
   <div class="faq_question_reply_container" style="">
       <div class="faq_question_container" style="">
        <span class="faq_question" style="">¿Esto es una prefunta seria asi que espero una respuesta seria?</span>
        <div class="faq_show_icon" style="">+</div>
    </div>
    <div class="faq_reply_container" style="">
        <p class="faq_reply" style="">Waynabox es una nueva forma de viajar por Europa. Te escaparás durante tres días a una ciudad sorpresa desde 150€, con vuelos de ida y vuelta y alojamiento incluidos.Descarta las ciudades que no quieres visitar (una gratuïta y, las siguientes, por 5€ cada una) y haz tu reserva. Dos días antes de salir, te mandaremos los billetes y descubrirás cuál es tu ciudad. ¡Atrévete a vivir tu próxima aventura este fin de semana!</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="faq_question_reply_container" style="">
       <div class="faq_question_container" style="">
        <span class="faq_question" style="">¿Esto es una prefunta seria asi que espero una respuesta seria?</span>
        <div class="faq_show_icon" style="">+</div>
    </div>
    <div class="faq_reply_container" style="">
        <p class="faq_reply" style="">Waynabox es una nueva forma de viajar por Europa. Te escaparás durante tres días a una ciudad sorpresa desde 150€, con vuelos de ida y vuelta y alojamiento incluidos.Descarta las ciudades que no quieres visitar (una gratuïta y, las siguientes, por 5€ cada una) y haz tu reserva. Dos días antes de salir, te mandaremos los billetes y descubrirás cuál es tu ciudad. ¡Atrévete a vivir tu próxima aventura este fin de semana!</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="faq_question_reply_container" style="">
       <div class="faq_question_container" style="">
        <span class="faq_question" style="">¿Esto es una prefunta seria asi que espero una respuesta seria?</span>
        <div class="faq_show_icon" style="">+</div>
    </div>
    <div class="faq_reply_container" style="">
        <p class="faq_reply" style="">Waynabox es una nueva forma de viajar por Europa. Te escaparás durante tres días a una ciudad sorpresa desde 150€, con vuelos de ida y vuelta y alojamiento incluidos.Descarta las ciudades que no quieres visitar (una gratuïta y, las siguientes, por 5€ cada una) y haz tu reserva. Dos días antes de salir, te mandaremos los billetes y descubrirás cuál es tu ciudad. ¡Atrévete a vivir tu próxima aventura este fin de semana!</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: ok, do you have any [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) link to this issue?